# exception: std::out_of_range at memory location when using erase

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I know what the error means and I know why it's throwing the error. However I do not understand as to how to resolve it. I have already read the other answers here on StackOverflow, which mostly tell what the error means.

I basically loop through elements, let the elements do something and then at the very end (outside of the loop), at the bottom of my method I use:

```
void someMethod()
{
    for (Wagon& wagon: wagons)
    {
         //some code
    }
    
    wagons.erase(std::remove_if(wagons.begin(), wagons.end(), [](const Wagon& wagon) { return !wagon.active; }), wagons.end());
}
```

The second iteration it throws `exception: std::out_of_range at memory location`.

Basically what I am trying to do is remove inactive wagons, so they do not get iterated through the second time it calls the method which loops through the wagons.

Comment: Please show the whole code fragment (a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: I cannot provide a reproducible code without shoving everything in the post. At best I can provide the method, which won't be "minimum reproducible example".

Comment: If an exception is thrown inside the loop, it's unlikely (although not impossible) that the code after the loop is the cause. My crystal ball thinks that the code inside your loop is modifying `wagons`, either directly or indirectly.

Comment: @codeling I made a clear change which should show my code structure. I know for a fact the erase part is causing the culprit.

Comment: @molbdnilo please see the edit. I think you missed it. It gives a better understanding of how my code looks like.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder What type is `wagons`? What's there in `Wagon`? The problem must be in the code you didn't show (e.g. `Wagon` move/copy constructors/operators). You most surely can provide a reproducible code without shoving everything in the post; it does require some extra effort on your part to strip everything down though.

Comment: Still: if the exception occurs in the second iteration of the loop, how did you conclude that `erase` is the problem?

Comment: It's also possible that the root cause is located quite far from this piece of code. Such is the beauty and majesty of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder The problem with Undefined Behavior errors in C++ is the symptoms are often observed far from the cause of the problem. It seems more than plausible there is a mistake in the loop that is corrupting the container in a way that causes `erase` or `remove_if` to fail later. A [MCVE] it often required to properly answer this type of question because the code shown does not seem to contain the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I am making this ballsy statement, because when I remove the erase piece, it can call my method every time without any problems. As a matter of fact, the program runs very well. It's that when I shove erase in it that it throws the error.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder There isn't enough information here to help you. All I can say is that the code shown does not contain the cause of your problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You were right. The culprit were 2 different parts of the code of which both were still using a hard-coded value.